Minimum of $x+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2-x}{1-2x}+\frac{1-2x}{2-x}$ where $x>2$
$$x+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2-x}{1-2x}+\frac{1-2x}{2-x},\qquad (x>2)$$
This is the function whose minimum value I want to find. I tried using the derivative but that is way too lengthy. The minimum value is $8$ and is attained at $x=2+\sqrt3$.
Is there any efficient way?

Use partial fractions before taking the derivative.  Then take out the common factor $(x^2-1)$

We can combine the terms as follows:
$$
\left( x+\frac{x-2}{2x-1} \right) + \left( \frac1x + \frac{2x-1}{x-2} \right) = 2(x^2-1) \left( \frac{1}{2x-1} + \frac{1}{x(x-2)} \right) \ge 2(x^2-1) \cdot \frac{4}{x^2-1} = 8.
$$
where I used AM-HM inequality. The inequality is saturated when
$$
2x-1 =x(x-2) \implies x^2-4x+1=0 \implies x = 2\pm \sqrt3.
$$
Since $x>2$, the minimum occurs at $x=2+\sqrt3$.

Why the downvote?

Your solution is soooooo smooth, I fixed that downvote

Here is a resolution which is probably not faster, but which exploit an interesting fact about $f(x)$ that may serve you in the future.
It is not too complicated to see that $f(x)=f(\frac 1x)$ indeed the third term transforms into the fourth one when applying $x\mapsto \frac 1x$.
So we will try to rewrite $f$ in term of $\ y=x+\frac 1x$
I spare you the calculation, from $f(x)-y\ $ I did remove $\frac 52$  to get an isolated $x$ on numerator, then take the inverse of that and do it again by removing $\frac {10}9$ and you get an expression in $y$ easy to recognize.
$$f(x)=\frac{y^2-4}{y-\frac 52}$$
This has a minimum in $y=4$ (still by differentiation, but a bit easier than for $f$) which correspond to $x=2\pm\sqrt{3}$, since we are interested in $x>2$ we can keep $2+\sqrt{3}$
but both give the same local minimum $\frac{4^2-4}{4-5/2}=8$

Answer to @Davide Masi
Let $g(x)=\frac{2-x}{1-2x}+\frac{1-2x}{2-x}$
Once reduced to same denominator we will get degree $2$ in numerator and denominator.
So let identify it to $\ a\cdot\frac{y+b}{y+c}=a\cdot\frac{x^2+bx+1}{x^2+cx+1}$
Numerator is $(2-x)^2+(1-2x)^2=5x^2-8x+5$
Denominator is $(2-x)(1-2x)=2x^2-5x+2$
And you find $\ a=\frac 52\ $for terms in $x^2$ then $b=-\frac 85,\ c=-\frac 52$
$$\text{Finally }\ f(x)=y+\tfrac 52\frac{y-\frac 85}{y-\frac 52}=y+\frac{5y-8}{2y-5}=\frac{y^2-4}{y-\frac 52}$$

I am interested in your method. Could you please elaborate on the calculations?

@DavideMasi I edited, with an identification method.

I got it. Thanks!

"by derivation" - Did you mean differentiation?

yes, not everyone is native English speaker and math terms are somewhat mixed sometimes -> edited
